# has_many and No method error issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two tables: Stores and products. The store model has a `has_many :products` and the products has a `belongs_to :store`

I'm trying to do this though in the rails console:

```
Store.where(open: true).products.where("created_at <= ?", 1.month.ago)
```

and get the error (paraphrased a bit): `NoMethodError: undefined method products for #<Store`

Comment: What does the schema look like for `Store`?

Comment: It has a `name:string`, and `open:boolean`, and id.

Comment: Can you have many open stores?

Comment: @locoboy, Yes there can be many open stores at a time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a very easy thing to do - `products` is a method defined on an instance of `Store` and you are calling it on the relation. I would probably go with:

```
Product.where(store_id: Store.where(open:true).pluck(:id)).where("created_at <= ?", 1.month.ago)
```

which would generate two db calls, but also returns a clean and easy to query scope. Another approach would be to use join:

```
Product.joins(:store).where(store: { open: true }).where("created_at <= ?", 1.month.ago)
```

This will do the work with one query, but due to the join it won't be that easy to manipulate the resulting scope that easily.

Comment: gah beat me to it :P. Also needs to be `joins` not `join` ;)

Answer (score 2):

You have it backwards. Since you can have many stores, Rails will not return all the products where `open: true`.

You need to join and lookup the products where the store is open.

```
Product.joins(:store).where(store: {open: true}).where("created_at <= ?", 1.month.ago)
```